# Toshiba Tecra A40 two finger scrolling activates right click

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, scrolling, alps

I'm trying to use Ubuntu 16.04 on a Toshiba Tecra A40 (ALPS touchpad) and I'm facing the following problem:

When using the two finger scrolling function, the context menu (i.e.: right click) is also activated continuously until I "untouch" the touchpad.

This means that it is almost impossible to scroll a web page (for example) without opening multiple new tabs...

I've already tryed Ubuntu 14.04, 16.10 and the version I wanted which is 16.04 LTS.

It is curious that before installing, the live version (right from the USB image) the problem does not exist. But after the installation process this issue arises on every version I tried.

Can anyone give me some pointers about what can I do to track the problem and possibly solve it?

Thank you.

**[Upgdate | available devices and details]**

```
user@computer:~$ xinput --list  
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer (2)]  
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - FHD                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And the details about the specific device ID, which I think it is the "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" (device ID = 11)

```
user@computer:~$ xinput list-props 11
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad':  
Device Enabled (140):   1  
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (142): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000  
Device Accel Profile (265): 1  
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   2.500000  
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000  
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    12.500000  
Synaptics Edges (269):  806, 4570, 230, 1306  
Synaptics Finger (270): 12, 15, 0  
Synaptics Tap Time (271):   180  
Synaptics Tap Move (272):   246  
Synaptics Tap Durations (273):  180, 100, 100  
Synaptics ClickPad (274):   0  
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (275):  75  
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (276):    141  
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (277):   7  
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (278): -111, -111  
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (279): 0, 0, 0  
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (280):   1, 1  
Synaptics Move Speed (281): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.035772, 0.000000  
Synaptics Off (282):    2  
Synaptics Locked Drags (283):   0  
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (284):   5000  
Synaptics Tap Action (285): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0  
Synaptics Click Action (286):   1, 1, 0  
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (287): 0  
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (288):    0.100000  
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (289): 0  
Synaptics Circular Pad (290):   0  
Synaptics Palm Detection (291): 0  
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (292):    10, 100  
Synaptics Coasting Speed (293): 20.000000, 50.000000  
Synaptics Pressure Motion (294):    15, 80  
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (295): 1.000000, 1.000000  
Synaptics Resolution Detect (296):  1  
Synaptics Grab Event Device (297):  0  
Synaptics Gestures (298):   1  
Synaptics Capabilities (299):   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0  
Synaptics Pad Resolution (300): 49, 45  
Synaptics Area (301):   0, 0, 0, 0  
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (302): 27, 27  
Device Product ID (260):    2, 8  
Device Node (261):  "/dev/input/event6"
```

The problem is that when I put two fingers on the TouchPad, it reacts as a "tap" and detects a right-click. This makes the two-finger scroll unusable on whatever the application I use (any browser, LibreOffice, etc.)

Any help would be more than welcome.
Thanks